# How to handle data driven input in this case?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, json

I am developing a small web page containing 2 nav panels, left and right.

leftNav: holds a list of flower names.

rigtNav: holds a bunch of images corresponding to the flower.

Like this -

```
|'''''''''''''''|''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''|
|               |                      Pics of Flower1 |
|  |'''''''|    |       |'''''|           |'''''|      |
|  |flower1|    |       |  A  |           |  C  |      |
|               |       |.....|           |.....|      |
|  |'''''''|    |                                      |
|  |flower2|    |                                      |
|               |       |'''''|           |'''''|      |
|  |'''''''|    |       |  B  |           |  D  |      |
|  |flower3|    |       |.....|           |.....|      | 
|               |                                      |
|...............|......................................|
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/3nJL9/1/)

My question is - If I have to make this a data-driven page. The input to get from a database, What is the effective way to get the data from the backend for rendering the page?

I am thinking of creating a json object with following format -

```
var data = {
    "Lotus" : [ "a1.jpg", "a1.jpg", "a1.jpg", "a1.jpg"  ], 

    "Orchid" : [ "o1.jpg", "o1.jpg", "o1.jpg", "o1.jpg"  ], 

    "Tulip" : [ "t1.jpg", "t1.jpg", "t1.jpg", "t1.jpg"  ], 

    "Rose" : [ "r1.jpg", "r1.jpg", "r1.jpg", "r1.jpg"  ], 
};
```

Is this a good way? Can anyone suggest me a better way?

Comment: I'm not sure I completely understand your question. You can most definitely use json generated by the server for this, which could result from a fairly simple ajax call to the back end.

Comment: I am just trying to explore possibilities beyond json. Trying to understand the differences and complexities in using them, if any.

Comment: I suggest json...but you can always use xml, which is a little heavier in terms of data size. There is also the really bad choice which is getting fully rendered html from the server. But that is highly inadvisable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JSON way of thinking would be to build a slightly more complex object, with properties describing exactly what each thing is. Below we have an array of objects:

```
var data = [
  {
    "name": "Lotus",
    "images": [ "a1.jpg", "a1.jpg", "a1.jpg", "a1.jpg"  ]
  },
  {
    "name": "Orchid",
    "images": [ "o1.jpg", "o1.jpg", "o1.jpg", "o1.jpg"  ]
  }
];
```

You can loop through this array and obtain information as `data[0].name` and `data[0].images[1]`.

Comment: perfect... but just thinking beyond json, Is there any other data structure supported through which we can achieve better results?

What i mean to ask is, is sending data through json the most effective way to handle data-driven websites? or is it more popular because its simple to implement?

Comment: JSON is compact, efficient, and easy to read and reference. XML is another less-popular option. Which one you use is ultimately up to you.

Comment: Makes sense. Appreciate your inputs!